# How did the Immortals know there would be a gathering?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

From the transcript of the first *Highlander* movie:

> Conner: What gathering?
>    Ramirez: When only a few of us are left we will feel an irresistible pull towards a faraway land to fight for the prize.

**How did Ramirez know that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a full canon answer, but looking at the whole franchise, Ramirez was probably told by older Immortals (which there were several, most notably, the Guardian of the Source from *Highlander 5*, Methos etc...); just like Connor MacLeod was told by Ramirez.

As far as how the original Immortal knew, it's not directly known from canon since the original source of Immortals is not really explored.

Comment: ... they're aliens!